# Django where to put static files

Tags: django, settings

I am using Django to create a small web app, however I do not know where i must put my HTML and JS files. I don't want to use the templateing system because I have no need to pass the values from Django directly to the HTML template, Instead the HTML will be static and I will fetch all the data necessary and send the data to be input back into the database using AJAX with Jquery.

My Question is where must I put my HTMl and JS files so they are accessible from the web browser and will be in the same directory so that I can send my ajax requests to something like

```
http://localhost:2000/webapp/RPC/updateitem/ (more stuff here)
```

and where the HTML files are

```
http://localhost:2000/webapp/index.html
```

Thanks,
RayQuang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You let your main webserver (the one you're running django on) deal with the static files. In most cases this means that you simly server the files through apache (or lighttpd or cherrypy or whatever). Django is only ment for the rendering of dynamic things and thus should not be used for serving static files.

If you're running from a development server (which I can't recommend), this tutorial will help you through setting it up: [Serving static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Well, the development server is considerably faster than Apache in your typical development setup when you don't want to restart the server every time the code changes. Whereas the development server can automatically reload sources, Apache starts a new instance of the interpreter altogether, going through a considerable cold start every time. Using nginx as a reverse proxy to the development WSGI server, whilst serving static files at the same time, beats Apache hands down.

Comment: I mostly put in the note about the development server since I don't think people should use it in production. Of course it's usage in development is perfectly fine and even encouraged (I use it all the time).

Comment: Yeah, I completely missed your emphasis on the main server context.